# how to create sitemap in cq5

Tags: extjs, aem, sitemap, sling

I have specific cq pages and external website pages that need to be displayed as links in sitemap page.

I came to know that I need to create a sitemap page component 
having xml.jsp that generates xml like

```
`<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
     <url> <loc>http://<host>/about_us.html</loc></url>
     <url> <loc http://<host>/about_us/<page-path>.html </loc> </url>
</urlset >`
```

and sitemap.jsp that reads the above xml and generate the html for sitemap page.

My understanding might not be correct, please correct me.
I am looking for some detailed example on what implementations I need to do to create sitemap with set of specific pages.

Thank you!

Comment: Simplest way possible would be to iterate over all your site pages in content hierarchy and render them over in HTML, as for the external pages, you could have a config to accept them or you can build a component where u can author all the external URLs. Finally combine the both the internal and external lists and render the HTML.

Comment: I don't think you should be displaying external links in a sitemap.